# Modify the UIButton's title label in custom view loaded from a XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

In my iOS project I load a custom view from a XIB file as depicted by Paul Solt within his CustomView (or CompositeXIB) tutorial.

```
_customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
[self addSubview:_customView];
```

In the custom view, I need to customize a button title according to the app state. So I added a IBOutlet UIButton property to modify the button's title label.

In the header file : `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;` (this property is linked to the appropriate UIButton in the XIB file)

In the init method from the implementation file : `_theButton.titleLabel.text = @"My own title";`

The button's title is well set after the init method overwriting this one defined in the XIB file as expected, but tapping the button causes the title defined in the XIB to be reset.
If the title is not defined in the XIB then the button's title remains always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set title for '`Normal`' as well as '`Selected`' states.

```
[YourButton setTitle:@"titleNormal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[YourButton setTitle:@"titleSelected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: You're right. I just found that I don't must to use the titleLabel attribut directly but the setTitle:forState method. Calling the method for the `UIControlStateNormal` is good enough as told in the Apple's doc: "If a title is not specified for a state, the default behavior is to use the title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state". Thanks for your very quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Please use settitle for UIControlState

```
  [buttonVariable setTitle:@"Your Title" forState:UIControlState)];
```

UIControlState's are

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlState) {
  UIControlStateNormal       = 0,
  UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
  UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
  UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
  UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
  UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
```